# Wix Custom action to set directory uses default value instead of value set in previous custom action

Tags: properties, directory, wix, custom-action

I want to use a custom action to set a property and then immediately use that newly set property's value to update a directory.  So far I have a custom action that finds an install path for a separate product using WMI and sets a property to that value.  When I turn around and use that property to set the directory, I get the old/default value instead of the new property value.

For context:

I have a directory structure like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="pf">
     <Directory Id="CompanyName" Name="$(var.companyName)">
       <Directory Id="FooProductName" Name="$(var.prodName)">
         <Directory Id="INSTALL_DIR">
           <Directory Id="PRODUCT_ROOT">
         </Directory>
         <Directory Id="FOO_DIR" Name="NotInstalled">
           <Directory Id="FOO_BINDIR" Name="bin" />
         </Directory>
       </Directory>
     </Directory>
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I have properties declared like this:

```
<Property Id="FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_CHECK_0" Value="AProductName" />
<Property Id="FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_DIR_0" Value="NotInstalledHere" />
```

I have custom actions declared like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="FooMoveFooDir" Directory="FOO_DIR" Value="[FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_DIR_0]" />
<CustomAction Id="GetInstallLocation" Return="check" BinaryKey="FooCAInstallLoc" DllEntry="GetInstallLocation" Execute="immediate" />
```

GetInstallLocation uses WMI to search for an installed product containing the value in FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_CHECK_0 and sets FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_DIR_0 to that value.  That it accomplishes this is borne out in the logging snippet below.

I have the following in <InstallExecuteSequence>

```
<Custom Action="FooMoveFooDir" After="CostFinalize">1</Custom>
<Custom Action="GetInstallLocation" Before="FooMoveFooDir">1</Custom>
```

Logging looks like this (from WiLogUtil):

```
(UNKNOWN)     Action ended 11:59:35: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:4C) [11:59:35:643]: Doing action: GetInstallLocation
(UNKNOWN)     Action 11:59:35: GetInstallLocation.
(UNKNOWN)     Action start 11:59:35: GetInstallLocation.
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:98) [11:59:35:665]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI2105.tmp, Entrypoint: GetInstallLocation
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:E4) [11:59:35:666]: Generating random cookie.
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:E4) [11:59:35:667]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 8872 (0x22A8).
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:34) [11:59:35:685]: Running as a service.
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:34) [11:59:35:687]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
(UNKNOWN)     SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI2105.tmp-\
(UNKNOWN)     SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
(UNKNOWN)     Calling custom action FOO.BAR.Installer.CustomActions.InstallLocation!FOO.BAR.Installer.CustomActions.InstallLocation.CustomActions.GetInstallLocation
(UNKNOWN)     Starting GetInstallLocation
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:34) [11:59:35:813]: Running as a service.
[ ... snip ... ]
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:A8) [11:59:40:635]: Running as a service.
(UNKNOWN)     Changing FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_DIR_0's value to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FOO Company\AProductName\
(UNKNOWN)     FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_DIR_0 = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FOO Company\AProductName\'
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:24) [11:59:40:664]: Running as a service.
[ ... snip ... ]
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:24) [11:59:44:420]: Running as a service.
(UNKNOWN)     Action ended 11:59:44: GetInstallLocation. Return value 1.
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:4C) [11:59:44:465]: Doing action: FooMoveFooDir
(UNKNOWN)     Action 11:59:44: FooMoveFooDir.
(UNKNOWN)     Action start 11:59:44: FooMoveFooDir.
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:4C) [11:59:44:467]: Note: 1: 1314 2: NotInstalledHere
(SERVER)     MSI (s) (20:4C) [11:59:44:467]: Note: 1: 1606 2: NotInstalledHere
(UNKNOWN)     Error 1606. Could not access network location NotInstalledHere.
```

It's setting the directory FOO_DIR to FOO_INSTALLLOCATION_DIR_0's default value instead of the value that was set by custom action in the immediately preceding step.  Searching indicates how to set a directory to a property value and how to set a property using a custom action in c#, but didn't turn up an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have tried this already, but anyways. Instead of using custom action to set the DIrectory Id directly, set the value through a property.

```
<Property Id="Foo_INSTALLDIR" /> 

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"> 

          <Directory Id="[Foo_INSTALLDIR]" Name="[Foo_INSTALLDIR]"> 

          </Directory>

</Directory>
```

see how I have used the Directory ***Id="[Foo_INSTALLDIR]"***

Check and let me know!

Comment: It gets us to more or less the same place :(  In both cases, it's setting up a directory at NotInstalledHere--just in one case the ID is 'FOO_DIR' and in the other it is 'NotInstalledHere'

Comment: Initially I think I got got confused with your question. Now I think I get your question, can you try this?

Custom Action="FooMoveFooDir" Before="CostFinalize">/Custom>

change the custom action to run before costfinalize?

Comment: It's shifting the Directory table about and compilation fails if this is tried before CostFinalize unfortunately.

On the other hand, I've had to change course dramatically as the target install machines don't necessarily have WMI Windows Installer Provider installed.  It's nowhere near as elegant but since we write registry keys for install location for our products already, I was able to set the property using a registry search and then use a custom action to update the directory value.  

...continued in next comment...

Comment: All of this leads me to believe that perhaps there is a disconnect between me updating the property in GetInstallLocation and what msiexec is seeing in the session database.  I'll need to revisit that block of code to make sure I've got the mapping from my convenience dictionary to the session database in a good place.

I am curious to know if others have tried this and if they've proven it works however.  My employer will definitely be trying this kind of thing with increasing frequency in the coming years.